# Opening a remote image on S3 in controller (ApplicationMailer) - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to open a profile picture uploaded to S3 through Paperclip, in order to submit it as an online attachment to an email.

Though I get error :

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen
```

Here is my bit of code in question :

```
attachments.inline['profilepic'] = File.read(profilepic)
```

`profilepic` being an absolute URL (starting with //mybucket.S3-eu-west..... ) to the image at S3 (when pasted onto the navbar, it just shows the image perfectly)

I have tried the following using open-uri, but same error

```
require 'open-uri'
attachments.inline['profilepic'] = open(profilepic)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you did, you need to first:

```
require 'open-uri'
```

and then do:

```
uri = URI("http:"+profilepic.to_s)
attachments["profilepic"] = open(uri).read
```

Comment: unfortunately still same error.. (btw I have added require 'open-uri' inside my mailer method,right before the remote file opening,  not sure if this is right)

Comment: Have you tried `open(URI.parse(profile_pic_url)).read`? and `require 'open-uri'` is usually put  at the top of your file.

Comment: now I get `no implicit conversion of URI::Generic into String` maybe it's because I am trying to parse an image ? (seems URI is taken in account though as the error seems URI related)

Comment: what's the url of your image ?

Comment: full error is : `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - //skeypesdev.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/profilepics/finalimages/000/000/003/small/24112014-DSC00522.jpg?1509137134` (link shown)

Comment: Your URI should look something like thid: `<URI::HTTP http://skeypesdev.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/profilepics/finalima%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bges/000/000/003/smal%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bl/24112014-DSC00522.%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bjpg?1509137134>` is that what you see ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157711/discussion-between-cyzanfar-and-maxence).

Comment: Ok found solution: add to uri my address and add http at the beginning which was missing. my browser guessed it but Rails needs something more explicit `uri = URI("http:"+profilepic.to_s)`

Comment: Awesome! I’ll update my answer accordingly. Happy you figured it out ;)