# Attach s3 object to SendGrid Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, sendgrid

I'd like to attach an image from s3 to a sendgrid email. Ideally there is no need to save the file on disk. How can I convert an object in s3 to a base64 encoded string?

```
      file = s3.get_object(bucket: "my_bucket",
        key: "key"
      )
      obj = {
        content: file.body.read,
        filename: "file_name"
      }
```

Note that the `file` is a `StringIO` object. This code also throws the following error `JSON::GeneratorError: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8`

How can I convert an object in s3 to a base64 encoded string?

Comment: is it a dynamic image, or a logo that you will embed in every email ? also I assume you want to inline attach the image, not only put a remote link in your HTML email ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode media in base64 given URL in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547008/how-to-encode-media-in-base64-given-url-in-ruby)

Comment: @Maxence it's a dynamic image that we don't want on a publicly accessible url so would like to attach it instead

Comment: Ok so you need a different image for each email. I do the same but with Paperclip and Url access : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990946/opening-a-remote-image-on-s3-in-controller-applicationmailer-no-such-file-or Though I will be of no further help as I don't know StringIO

Comment: but basically you just have to pass your object to `attachments.inline["image.png"]` I think it's automatically base64 encoded. Though if your document is an image with different mime type, you have to build the name with correct type (image.png, image.gif..) or your email won't be able to grab the attached file