# Rails Mailer Attaching Uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, actionmailer

After a user uploads multiple images to my site, I want those images to be emailed to me immediately.

I've tried just sending the first uploaded image to see if I could just get that to work.  I keep getting this error: `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

I've played around in the console and can't get the file location with `exists?` to evaluate to `true`

```
 def send_appointment_request(user)
    @user = user
    attachments.inline[@user.inquirer_attachments] = File.read(Rails.root + "#{@user.inquirer_attachments.first.image}".to_s)
    mail(to: "me@email.com", from: @user.email, subject: "An Appointment Request Has Been Made")        
  end
```

Overall, the above code is just a test to send the first image to get this to work.

Can someone give me a hand for solution that allows me to send multiple images that are not static?

Comment: Where is located the image you are trying to attach ?

Comment: @Maxence it's in a model called ```inquirer_attachment``` that has a belongs_to association with ```user```

Comment: is it stored remotely on S3 or such? is `#{@user.inquirer_attachments.first.image}` a remote link to your image ?

Comment: It will be when in production, but currently it's just saved at the generic ```:file``` location.  Here's uploader directory in case it helps: ```def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end```

Comment: I had same problem for a remote image, see this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990946/opening-a-remote-image-on-s3-in-controller-applicationmailer-no-such-file-or though you are local... I would suggest trying to print `#{@user.inquirer_attachments.first.image}` and see what it returns